# My API is called twice

Tags: php, laravel, mod-rewrite, curl

I'm using `laravel 5.2`, I have a problem with my cURL request, the API is **called twice**.

I tried to execute the same code on a **single .php** file without laravel and **everything is ok**.

I see on the web that may come from the **mod_rewrite rules** because of parameters but I don't know how check that.

**My function look like this :**

```
$url = 'http://api.com/api.asmx/deepSearchCreate';
$ch = curl_init($url);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, 'apikey=API_KEY&search='.strip_tags(trim($article->contenu)).'&source=&searchid=');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

$response = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

$xml = simplexml_load_string($response, 'SimpleXMLElement', LIBXML_NOCDATA);
$json = json_encode($xml);
$array = json_decode($json, TRUE);

$id = $array['collection']['@attributes']['id'];
```

**Httacces :**

```
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
    <FilesMatch "\.(eot|font.css|otf|ttc|ttf|woff)$">
        Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
    </FilesMatch>
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Deny access to framework directories
    RewriteRule ^(app/|bootstrap/|config/|database/|resources/|storage/tests|vendor/) - [R=404,L,NC]

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

    # And dot files/folders (for example .env)
    RedirectMatch 404 /\..*$

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: @Robert Are you sure ? How can i fix that ?

Comment: It was sarcasm, if I were you I would go through debbuger and see what happens also you can use some "exit" or "die" and then see if it is called once

Comment: @Robert I tried to write in a file and everything is ok, no duplicate. I think the probleme is the parameters in the curl URL

Comment: or the file you're requesting has bugs in it, like @Robert said, you need to debug better.

Comment: I will install debugbar laravel

Comment: Note : It was laravel 5.2 sorry my bad @Robert

Comment: How is it being executed? Via console or when you open proper url in your browser?